# Can you get duplicate puzzle pieces in the Mii Plaza?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

On the Mii plaza puzzles, when using coins to generate puzzle pieces, is it possible to get duplicate pieces?

When I was doing this last night, one of the panels had only two left for completion and I got a piece at random, but it was one I already had, I think.  Am I mistaken, or was there a glitch?  I was clicking the confirm pretty quick with the speed up held down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can happen that a piece is chosen that you already have, because it is randomly chosen. If a piece is brought to you by the bird that you already have, nothing happens. If a piece you don't have is picked, it will be added to your collection. In both cases you lost your coins however. You can also hear the difference, because a newly piece will generate a tingeling sound, and when you'll get nothing, there is no extra sound.

So **yes**, it is possible to collect a double piece, but it will have no consequences.

Comment: Note that you can't get a duplicate from a completed picture. This means it's often worthwhile to use streetpass tags to complete nearly-done pictures, so play coin usage is directed towards pictures with a lower probability of getting a duplicate.

Comment: The only consequence was a wasted 2 play coins. Remember that.